# Importxml Xpath returning content empty

Tags: xml, xpath, import, google-sheets

I am trying to get some info imported into a Google Spreadsheet.

I have tried IMPORTHTML("Address","table") and IMPORTXML("Address,"XPATH").

But both of them return No Content.

I have a Chrome Extension installed called XPath Helper, which has given me the following XPATH: `//div[@class='announcements']//h4`

The website is internal, so it might not link externally. Here is a screenie with XPATH highlighting what it SHOULD be pulling into the Goolge Sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siMbd.jpg

The web address in question is: https://sites.google.com/a/partnershipservices.co.uk/opsbridge-extras/announcements

And I'm trying to pull in the Announcement titles. Can anyone help me out with this? AFAIK it should be working, and I have no idea why it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use importxml/importhtml like that unless it can reach the data without credentials

Comment: Ah balls. I was hoping that being within the same domain would make it work. I guess not. Ok, thanks for letting me know Aurielle.

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to use apps scripts to try and authenticate through appfetch , but it would take a bit of digging to determine if you can even make that work, it changes per scenario , and per site your trying to access etc